# New to Magical Record: context not creating rows in datastore

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a Core Data based app that I decided to try with Magical Record.  (basically MR seems to do many of the things a helper class I wrote does)

However, it created the database, based on the model, but when I try and save the context with a new inserted object, it appears to succeed, but nothing is created in the database.  I have stepped through to ensure that the new object is in the context which is about to save, I tell it to save, there is no error created, but there is no data.  I assume there is something obvious I am missing here.

```
- (void)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context withMessage:(NSString*)messageString
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *message = messageString;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = nil;
    if (!context) {
        managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext];
    } else {
        managedObjectContext = context;
    }
    if(!message) {
        message = @"Data Saved";
    }
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
        [managedObjectContext save:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Save Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save Successful!"
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}
```

Any insight?  As I mentioned, I can confirm that the stack is set up (I did so in the App Delegate's applicationDidFinishLoading method, naming the store), and that the corresponding database exists in the expected location, with the appropriate tables.  I can confirm that the expected newly inserted object exists in the managedObjectContext's insertedObjects, and that there are no errors resulting from the save.  However, after the save, the data is not there.  (nor is it in the managedObjectContext, obviously)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're actually saving an entity, or making changes to an entity in that code.

Also worthy of note, you're doing far too much work in that code. You probably want to do something more like:

```
- (void) saveMyEntity:(NSObject<NSManagedObject *>) yourEntity;
{
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){

        yourEntity.message = @"something new";

    } completion:^{
        <UIAlert stuff here>
    }];
}
```

MagicalRecord provides an easy to use API that hides quite a bit of the tedium of remembering how to save data, etc. It's probably good to read up on the README file.

Comment: Well, that was my save method.  I call it in another class where I create and insert the object.  So you are saying I should not use this:  [managedObjectContext save:&error]; to save the context?  I have read the read me and I don't see where it suggests that telling the context to save won't save in the usual way.  As I say apparently I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I still have no idea what was wrong with my code, but not using the NSManagedObjectContext's save method seems to have worked.  Instead I did this:

```
- (void)saveContextWithMessage:(NSString*)messageString
{
    NSString *message = messageString;
    if (!message) {
        message = @"Data Saved";
    }
    [MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext* localContext){}
                                  completion:^{
                                  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save Successful!"
                                                                                  message:message
                                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                  [alert show];
    }];
}
```

As indicated, I was doing things in code that MR does for me, so I removed that to make it clearer.